# How to read values that are stored as bitmasks using R?

Tags: r

I have downloaded a nc file from

```
f=open.ncdf("0101.nc")
dimensions:"
[1] "Longitude   Size: 1440"
[1] "Latitude   Size: 720"
[1] "------------------------"
```

I then wanted to use this: `Bit Mask`

```
A = get.var.ncdf(nc=f,varid="mask",verbose=TRUE)
```

I typed `A` but I found the values are

```
       0 2 4 6 8 12 16 24 32 34 40 64 128
```

However the originator of the files said that this is BitMAsks and gave me this classifications:

The zen condition is included in the bit mask with the first bit (as 2^1; following the C convention we count from zeroth bit) turned on.  Here is the list of the bit definitions:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These types of mask fields aren't all that uncommon when trying to efficiently store data in a binary format. First, we can translate your table of 2^n values to integers for the decoding

```
vv<-c("not land"=1,"ice"=2, "no valid data"=4, "high depth"=8,
    "high depth in band"=16, "negatl depth in-band"=32,
    "negepth in-band"=64, "no tband"=128, "no nband"=256)
```

Then you can use a function like this to do the decoding

```
decode<-function(x) {
    sapply(x, function(z) {
        paste(names(vv[bitwAnd(z,vv)>0]), collapse=",")
    })
}
```

Here we use `bitwAnd()` to compare the observed value to each of the potential flags. If we want to see all the possible values, we can do

```
decode(sort(unique(c(A))))

#  [1] ""                              "ice"                          
#  [3] "no valid data"                 "ice,no valid data"            
#  [5] "high depth"                    "high depth in band"           
#  [7] "high depth,high depth in band" "negatl depth in -band"        
#  [9] "negepth in-band"               "no tband"
```

Or you can decode one at a time

```
decode(16)
# [1] "high depth in band"
```

Comment: If you do `decode(24)` you will see that certain values are combinations of flags. 24 is 8+16 so it has two flags. 34 would be 2+32. The decode function pastes the values together with a ","